# reusable function in jquery, how to pass calling item's value/id?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of about 3 items. I would like to create a jquery function that will trigger whenever one of those list items is clicked. The function should then be able to do something using the value or attribute of the html list item.  So that in the following code when I click on button 2 I get an alert box with the value 2 displayed.

```
<ul>
 <li class="myclick" id="1">Test Me</li>
 <li class="myclick" id="2">Test Me 2</li>
 <li class="myclick" id="3">Test Me 3</li>
```

```
 $.fn.myFunction = (function() {
          alert(this.id);
          });         
 $(function () {
       $(".myclick").click(function(){
                $().myfunction("Test");
      });
```

I know it's  a pretty basic question but I'm very much new at Jquery and am trying teach myself.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ayokeb/1/edit)*

```
// PLUGIN method
$.fn.myFunction = (function() {
   this.click(function(){
          alert(this.id);
   });
});   

$(function(){  // DOM READY
  
    $(".myclick").myFunction(); // BIND PLUGIN TO .myclick elements

});
```

P.S, if one day you got scared seeing the use of `prototype` somewhere, ... try it right now, instead of `fn` use `prototype` :D

Than you can use also *named functions:*

```
function alertID() {
   alert(this.id);
}   

$(function(){
  
    $(".myclick").click( alertID );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to extend jQuery to do this .. you can just use any old generic function:

```
myFunction = function () { alert(this.id); }
$(".myclick").on('click', myFunction);
```

This calls `myFuntion` using the clicked element as the context.

If you wanted to use the code you already had, you would just have to use `$(this).myFunction();` instead of `$().myFunction`

Answer (score -1):

first of all **you don't need to extend through jQuery** for this tiny task.

here is what you can do..

```
//looping through each li in ul
$('ul li').each(function(){
    //attach click event to li this refers to li here
    $(this).click(function(){
      //to alert ID of this list this refers to li here
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
      // to alert Text or html within li
     alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: As talking about `reusable function` (read the Q.) how can I use your exact function for e.g: `span` element?

Comment: hi roXon, if im not mistaken you are talking about span inside li . in case im wrong please correct me. For span you can write something like : alert($(this).next('span').html()) ... inside click function.

Comment: no, sorry, I was talking generally, on how to create a reusable function means that you have a function that encapculates some work to do, than you call the function for ANY (and here I was meaning for e.g. some `span` elements) element you want. And BTW you don't need at all the `each` method cause the `ul li` is already a collection of all your `li` elements inside the DOM. Edit your answer before you get a collection of downvotes ;)

Comment: no sorry. as per my understanding i dont think this is possible to iterate through all li under ul wihtout each. if u know please share that would be appericiated. Secondly im showing how value or id can be accessed via click.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ayokeb/6/edit I'll add you a -1. You could do test by your self. Please review your answer and fix your errors.

Comment: i think you dont read what i wrote. i asked you to correct or edit the post. however u r behvaing like an author. please now stop adding comment to this post and being arrogant.

Comment: Sorry, but we're all hear to learn and teach. Get upvotes and downvotes. Es per I always review my downvotes and for the sake of the content and quality of the answers given here I did my best to suggest you, **as answerer**. AS I think you have enough knowledge to edit your post, I thought was unnecessary for me to do it. No hard feelings. Review your answer and be sure I'll be the first to give cudos to you! :)